# Is a block size of 4 MiB on a partition of 99.06 GiB too big?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

Its a new laptop I'm using, and currently installing Ubuntu 13.10

I am having to move 3 NTFS partitions to right, grow two of them to 99 GiB, and shrink one of them to 55.46 GiB.

So to do this GParted is using a block size of 4.00 MiB on one of the partitions. This particular partition will be used to store Music and Movies, so a combination of both small and large sized files. Is the block size of 4.00 MiB too large on this partition?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on size of whole drive. If your drive is bigger than 750 GB it is highly recommended to use block size 4 MiB. Otherwise, you can use smaller, for example 500 KiB.